# Query Optimization for if exists sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I am trying to optimize the query below

```
if exists (select 1 
           from GHUB_DISCREPANCY_REPORT (NOLOCK) 
           where PARTNO = @currentpn and orderID = @oldorderid + 1 
             and (Discr_Fox_Available = 'Y' 
                  or Discr_Fox_NC = 'Y' or Discr_FOC_Available = 'Y' 
                  or Discr_FOC_NC = 'Y' or Discr_Cpa_Available = 'Y' 
                  or Discr_Cpa_NC = 'Y' or Discr_Fox_Tot = 'Y' 
                  or Discr_FOC_Tot = 'Y' or Discr_Cpa_Tot = 'Y'))
```

I indexed the primary key, PartNo, Aging and OrderID columns.

Is there any other way I can optimize this query ?

Please suggest!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: In what context is this EXISTS being executed - in a Stored Procedure, a function, elsewhere? How long is taking to run right now typically and how many rows in GHUB_DISCREPANCY_REPORT ?

Comment: Lets see your execution plan

Comment: In Stored Procedure,right now for 53 rows its taking 10 sec.

Comment: If the variables you are using in your WHERE statements are parameters of the Stored Procedure, don't do that. Instead, define new variables within the stored procedure. Assign them the values from the parameters, and then use those in your statement. You'll get a better compile from it. You could be a victim of "parameter sniffing".

Comment: @The TTG , I am editing my SP, i will let you know performance improment after that.

Comment: @TheTTGGuy performace is better now its taking 8sec for 53 rows.Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: That's still too slow, in my opinion. Glad to help but I think you should keep looking. What is the total size of the entire GHUB_DISCREPANCY_REPORT table - 53?

Comment: the total rows are 1077957 ,reserved space 283936 KB and unused space 3184 KB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try an index on `GHUB_DISCREPANCY_REPORT(PARTNO, orderId)`.  This may be a big help for you query.

If you still have performance problems, one method is to use to separate queries, each of which can be optimized with a separate index.

```
if exists (select 1 
           from GHUB_DISCREPANCY_REPORT (NOLOCK) 
           where PARTNO = @currentpn and orderID = @oldorderid and Discr_Fox_Available = 'Y' 
          ) or
    . . .
```

And then having a separate composite index for each combination: `GHUB_DISCREPANCY_REPORT(PARTNO, orderId, Discr_Fox_Available)`.  This is a lot of index overhead, but could be worth it.

Another idea is to combine all the flags into one:

```
alter table GHUB_DISCREPANCY_REPORT 
    add Any_Flags as (case when (Discr_Fox_Available = 'Y' 
                  or Discr_Fox_NC = 'Y' or Discr_FOC_Available = 'Y' 
                  or Discr_FOC_NC = 'Y' or Discr_Cpa_Available = 'Y' 
                  or Discr_Cpa_NC = 'Y' or Discr_Fox_Tot = 'Y' 
                  or Discr_FOC_Tot = 'Y' or Discr_Cpa_Tot = 'Y' then 'Y' else 'N' end);
```

You can add an index on a computed column and then use the value in your query:

```
create index idx_GHUB_DISCREPANCY_REPORT_anyflags on GHUB_DISCREPANCY_REPORT(PARTNO, OrderId, AnyFlags);

if exists (select 1 
           from GHUB_DISCREPANCY_REPORT (NOLOCK) 
           where PARTNO = @currentpn and orderID = @oldorderid and AnyFlags = 'Y' 
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

"top 1 1 from tbl_name" gives much better performance than " select 1" in the "if exists" (sub query) part.

Refer to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009022/select-top-1-1-vs-if-existsselect-1)

After using "top 1 1" estimated number of rows is reduce to 1 from 135765 in my case.

Comment: I don't understand why you unaccepted my answer.   The accepted answer on the discussion you allude to has neither a subquery nor `top 1`.  The discussion is on another topic, mostly (the difference between `exists` and `count(*)`).