# What is a better alternative to procedural approach to produce a string based on columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on making string based on column values. Example:

```
SELECT @Registered = a.hasRegistered
    ,@Subscribed = a.hasSubscribed
FROM AuthorData a
WHERE a.authorId = 10 --@AUTHORID

IF (@Registered  = 1)
    SET @ReturnString = @ReturnString + '0,'

IF (@Subscribed = 1)
    SET @ReturnString = @ReturnString + '1,'

IF EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 name
        FROM AUTHORDATA AS A
            INNER JOIN AUHTORPROFILE B on A.AUTHORID=B.AUTHORID
            INNER JOIN AUTHORHISTORY C ON B.AUTHORPROFILEID=C.AUTHORPROFILEID
        WHERE ISNULL(AUTHORDATA.authorId, 0) = 10 --@AUTHORID
        )
BEGIN
    SET @ReturnString = @ReturnString + '10,'
END

select CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), STUFF(@ReturnString, LEN(@ReturnString), 1, ''))
```

This performs the calculation for 1 author (based on WHERE clause IN 2 places -> **authorId=10**)

I can make this into a function and then call from a select query as follows:

```
SELECT *,FN_CALCUALTE_OPTIONS(AUTHORID)
FROM AUTHORDATA
```

I want to ask if there is any way so I can do the calculations in the above SELECT query rather than create the function?

I have tried:

```
SELECT *,CASE WHEN A.hasRegistered=1 THEN '0,' ELSE '' END + 
    CASE WHEN A.hasSubscribed=1 THEN '1,' ELSE '' END
FROM AUTHORDATA as A
```

How can I have the exists part of select?

Comment: Im already doing that (as shown at the bottom). Then for the exists I am thinking of using a LEFT JOIN. Am I on right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way IMO is to move your criteria being found via `EXISTS` to an `OUTER APPLY`. Like so:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), STUFF(calc.ReturnString, LEN(calc.ReturnString), 1, ''))
FROM 
    AUTHORDATA AS A
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) 
                    1 AS Found 
                FROM 
                    AUHTORPROFILE AS B 
                    INNER JOIN AUTHORHISTORY AS C ON B.AUTHORPROFILEID = C.AUTHORPROFILEID
                WHERE 
                    B.authorId = A.authorId) AS lookup_author
    /*outer apply here just for readibility in final select*/
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT 
                    CONCAT(CASE WHEN A.hasRegistered = 1 THEN '0,' ELSE '' END
                          ,CASE WHEN A.hasRegistered = 1 THEN '1,' ELSE '' END
                          ,CASE WHEN lookup_author.Found = 1 THEN '10,' ELSE '' END) AS ReturnString) AS calc;
```

Then you can use `lookup_author.Found = 1` to determine that it was found in your lookup. From there, you just have to apply the rest of your conditions correctly via `CASE` statements and then use your final `SELECT` over the result.

Comment: What is the harm in using EXISTS in the SELECT clause itself (correlated subquery), rather than using the APPLY approach?

Comment: I wouldn't so much say the harm is in the EXISTS operator in the SELECT clause, but more the correlated subquery. Let's say you need to use the output of a correlated subquery in multiple places in your SELECT. Depending on how it is used, you could get a query plan that runs that correlated subquery multiple times whereas using the OUTER APPLY can be referenced as many times as needed and you don't run that risk. Additionally, let's say you need to return a column value from your correlated subquery. You cant do that using EXISTS and would have to refactor your code. So I prefer OUTER APPLY.

Comment: Not to mention the OUTER APPLY method provides much cleaner and easier to read code IMO

Comment: If I were not to use the readability purpose outer apply (the 1st outer apply), am I correct that I would then have to replace the `lookup_author.Found = 1` with `CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM  AUHTORPROFILE AS B  INNER JOIN AUTHORHISTORY AS C ON B.AUTHORPROFILEID = C.AUTHORPROFILEID WHERE  B.authorId = A.authorId )` or could even be `CASE WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM  AUHTORPROFILE AS B  INNER JOIN AUTHORHISTORY AS C ON B.AUTHORPROFILEID = C.AUTHORPROFILEID WHERE  B.authorId = A.authorId ) =1`

Comment: Sorry, the readability comment was for the second `OUTER APPLY`. But yes what you have in your comment should be the equivalent of the first `OUTER APPLY`. Again, I prefer not to have correlated subqueries in my `SELECT` clause for the above stated reasons. But if you are going to do so, in this case I would likely use the `EXISTS` operator. It makes your intent a bit more clear when read inline. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009022/select-top-1-1-vs-if-existsselect-1) answer.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you can put them all together into a single query as follows. If you didn't need the final stuff you would just have a regular query, but because you need to use the results twice in the stuff `CROSS APPLY` is a convenient way to calculate it once and use it twice. Also you can correlate your sub-query since you are using the same `AuthorData` record.

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), STUFF(X.ReturnString, LEN(X.ReturnString), 1, ''))
FROM AuthorData a
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
    (
        CASE WHEN a.hasRegistered = 1 THEN '0,' ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN a.hasSubscribed = 1 THEN '1,' ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM AUHTORPROFILE B
            INNER JOIN AUTHORHISTORY C ON B.AUTHORPROFILEID = C.AUTHORPROFILEID
            WHERE B.AUTHORID = a.AuthorId
        )
        THEN '10,' else '' end
    )
) AS X (ReturnString)
WHERE a.AuthorId = 10 --@AUTHORID
```

Comment: Is this a better approach then using the CASE/EXIST directly in the SELECT (as a correlated subquery)?

Comment: I want to ask whether VALUES is does something different from using SELECT?

Comment: @Variable I recommend reading the documentation for `VALUES` - it only allows essentially static values, but multiple rows (so easier than unioning all a bunch of selects), whereas a select allows to select from an actual table. In this case either works well. As for case exists directly in select, as I mention in my answers, stuff requires that values twice, so you would have to repeat the same logic two times... this way avoids that. Repeating logic twice is asking for trouble because nothing ensures they remain identical.

Comment: Fantastic answer sir. I had something I was going to post but this is so much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a single CASE statement and get data as given below. Make sure that you are covering every possible condition.

```sql
SELECT *, CASE WHEN a.Registered =1 AND a.Subscribed =1  
               AND EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1
               FROM AUHTORPROFILE B on 
               INNER JOIN AUTHORHISTORY C ON B.AUTHORPROFILEID=C.AUTHORPROFILEID
               WHERE B.AUTHORID =A.AUTHORID) THEN '0,1,10'

               WHEN a.Registered =1 AND a.Subscribed =0  
               AND EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1
               FROM AUHTORPROFILE B on 
               INNER JOIN AUTHORHISTORY C ON B.AUTHORPROFILEID=C.AUTHORPROFILEID
               WHERE B.AUTHORID =A.AUTHORID) THEN '0,10'

               WHEN a.Registered =0 AND a.Subscribed =1  
               AND EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1
               FROM AUHTORPROFILE B on 
               INNER JOIN AUTHORHISTORY C ON B.AUTHORPROFILEID=C.AUTHORPROFILEID
               WHERE B.AUTHORID =A.AUTHORID) THEN '1,10'

               WHEN a.Registered =0 AND a.Subscribed =0  
               AND EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1
               FROM AUHTORPROFILE B on 
               INNER JOIN AUTHORHISTORY C ON B.AUTHORPROFILEID=C.AUTHORPROFILEID
               WHERE B.AUTHORID =A.AUTHORID) THEN '10'
               END AS CalculateOptions

FROM AUTHORDATA AS a
```